# Should we use "a" or "the" before date

Tags: articles

Is this correct to write:

> Result of car accident in different date.

or this:

> Result of car accident in a different date.
>   Result of car accident in the different date.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a source (where are you using this phrase?), so we can apply more context to your phrase/s.

Comment: Hi @user1436187 Did Angela's answer answer your question? If so, don't forget to click the tick to accept the answer; if not, feel free to edit your question to explain more clearly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People have written pages and pages on the use of the zero, definite and indefinite articles in English. Here, I will attempt to give simple rules of thumb that explain why the following sentence can use an indefinite article:

> This was the result of a car accident on **a** different date.

## Rules of Thumb

**1. The indefinite article "a/an"** is used:

- with countable nouns, e.g.: a house, an apple
- to refer to an entity belonging to a generic class, e.g.: I'm a doctor. Of all the possible doctors, I'm one of them.

**2. The definite article "the"** is used:

- with countable nouns, e.g.: the house
- with uncountable nouns, e.g.: the food
- to refer to a specific entity known to the reader, e.g.: the house I live in, the food in my plate

**3. The zero article** is used:

- to refer to a generic class, e.g.: cats, air
- with countable nouns in the plural form, e.g.: cats are better than dogs
- with uncountable nouns in the singular form, e.g.: dry air contains 78.09% nitrogen, 20.95% oxygen, 0.93% argon, 0.039% carbon dioxide and small amounts of other gases.

## Examples of Use for "date"

Below I'm giving examples of use of the articles described above with the countable noun "date":

1. Use of the indefinite article

   > Please, choose **a date** in March.
2. Use of the definite article

   > I haven't forgotten **the date** I met you.
3. Use of the zero article:

   > **Dates** must be formatted using the ISO standard

## This was the result of a car accident on a different date.

And lastly, let's explain the use of "a" in the OP's sentence. Here, although "a different date" is referring to a specific date, the reader is not told exactly which date the accident happened, and thus the indefinite article "a" is used.

Note that one could contrive enough context so that the use of "the different date" is also possible:

> This car has suffered three collisions.
>   Two of the collisions happened on the same date.
>   This scratch is the result of the collision **on the different date**.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "on", and put "a" before car accident.  Here are some examples:

This was the result of a car accident on a different date.

The dent in the car was the result of a car accident on a different date.

Answer (score 0):

An action occurs/happens **on** a date or **at** a time

he did it **on** Wednesday
or
she did it **at** 12 o'clock

I would just like to make you aware though that you need to put **a** car accident.

To maximise the skill level in this sentence, consider:

> the result of a car accident on an unrelated occasion.